# creating table in database bookshelf where one book can have multiple category

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm creating a database of bookshelf.

I have a table named BookInfo which contains information regarding book title , category and many other properties related to it.

I have different table named category which have categoryID and categoryName with it.

**Problem** : I want to insert multiple category for single book information.waht would be the feasible solution.

Comment: A separate category table.

Comment: add bookinfo id as foreign_key in category table

Comment: @noddy -  but That wiil creating multiple category with same name. I have a scenario where new book is added in bookInfo table and It can have multiple category like fiction, Non-fiction, romance etc. your solution will keep adding same categories in cateogory table.

Comment: can you provide dummy entries?

Comment: @jarlh - As I mentioned in the question. I already have category table. Will you elobare more in detail so I can understand if I haven't please :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, didn't read carefully enough. (Again...)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is normalize your DB.

Is not correct if you have more Category tables. You must use one Category table, then to link it to your BookInfo table you must create a middle table, for example, named, CategoryBook, where your middle table must be these fields:

```
ID (your PK table)
field PK BookInfo (as FK)
field PK Category (as FK)
```

Alternatively, your middle table can be built as follow:

```
PK BookInfo (as FK)
PK Category (as FK)
```

where two upper field are the PK of your table

Answer (score 2):

You can create a mapping table as "Book_Category" which will have 
BookID, CategoryID and if you want create a composite primary key for "Book_Category" table by combining both the columns.

Comment: I add a feeling this might be the only solution. just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: Yes, and using this you can keep your database normalise. :)

Comment: one more thing. What kind of field I should define if I want to add same book with multiple edition?  please provide datatype as well :)

Comment: I think you should treat the different edition of the same book as an entire new book. And you can create a separate column as "IsRelatedTo" and store the Id(primary key) of previous edition. Pls feel free to ask more questions, if I'm not clear.

Comment: I thought about your solution but insertion will be quite infeasible in this situation. user will have to remember the bookId number to insert if he's doing insertiong directly from database client using SQL query.

Comment: I ineed a solution where I will be inserting a new book but I can distinguish that this book is a new edition of some previous book. If there isn't any other solution availble then we can go with above solution.

Comment: Okay, here is one more solution but personally I will not recommend this one, you can just have one column as "IsSequel" or "IsVersioned" with datatype 'bit', if the value is '0' then consider it as a new book and if value is '1' then its the new version of previous book. In this case you don't have to remember the Id of previous version of this book but at the same you will not be able to find to which book series this new book belongs.

Comment: Okay. Seems like the previous one is much better. Thanks for your time though :)

Answer (score 2):

You must have one more table to handle it.
OR
You have to add into BookInfo table only.
OR
Category column should hold different categoryID's